# Showing these prime ideals are principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ be a number field where $\theta$ has minimal polynomial $x^3-9x-6$. I had to factorise the ideals $(2)$ and $(3)$ into prime ideals, for which I got $(2) = (2,\theta)(2,\theta +1)^2$ and $(3) = (3,\theta)^3$ by using Dedekind's criterion.

Then I am to show these prime ideals are principal. I'm a bit stuck at this point. The best I can think to do is to choose some element I might believe generates the whole ideal and show that we can obtain the generators from it. I've had a few guesses for only $(2,\theta)$ and I can't manage to get there.

I imagine there is a better way to do this than to simply strike it lucky with a good guess. Is there a better way to proceed in finding a generator, or maybe some other method of showing the ideals are principal?

Comment: There may be a way of calculating these specific ones, but I'm not aware of any way round doing some brutal computations in general. For questions like this, I would recommend using a computer. Try SAGE

Comment: You might try computing the norm of $(2,\theta)$ and trying to find an element of $K$ with that norm.

Comment: @rogerl of course caluclating norms means finding a 3x3 determinant. I don't see a clean way of doing questions like this by hand

Comment: @Mathmo123 Agreed; it just seemed unlikely to me that the OP was given a problem (this sounds like a class assignment) requiring the use of technology...

Comment: @rogerl I remember being set a more or less identical problem in a number theory class where the point of the question was to demonstrate that you couldn't do it by hand

Comment: @rogerl the problems with computing the norm of $(2,\theta)$ or even searching like that are that there are two primes above $2$ in $K$, so that even if you find one, it's hard to tell sometimes if you've got one generating $(2,\theta)$ rather than $(2,\theta+1)$, especially since the unit group is not finite. Also searching for explicit elements by knowing just the norm seems like a tall order (though perhaps there is something known to the applied people, my answer obviously betrays my loyalty to theory).

Comment: @Mathmo123 the main trick is to not try and actually **find** a generator, so much as show one exists. You have a good point that if we were searching by-hand, testing would be an untenable way to and solving in general requires solving a cubic equation in three unknowns (yuck!). You're also right that there's no clean, general approach to questions like this: Proving principality is hard to do, finding a generator is often impossible, though in some lucky cases the theory allows us to evade having to actually do the work if we're lucky (this is indeed one such case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
As is usual, we let $q(x)=q_\theta(x)=x^3-9x-6$. As Jyrki notes, $q(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\theta+1$, but then $(\theta+1,2)=(\theta+1, (\theta+1)p(\theta))$ for some polynomial $p(x)\in\mathcal{O}_K$, so that $(\theta+1,2)=(\theta+1)$ is principal.

So let's do the others. Since $2\in (\theta+1)$ we have that there exists $p(x)\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$ so that $2=(\theta+1)p(\theta)$. We note that $\theta^3-9\theta-6=0$ is equivalent to

> $$\theta(\theta-3)(\theta+3)=2\cdot 3$$

Then writing this as $\theta(\theta+1-4)(\theta+1+2)=2\cdot 3$ we see that this makes $\theta\cancel{(\theta+1)}(1-(\theta+1)p(\theta)^2)(1+p(\theta))=3\cancel{(\theta+1)}p(\theta)$.

Since the other two factors on the LHS are congruent to $1$ modulo $p(\theta)$ we must have that $\theta\in (p(\theta))$ since reduction modulo $(p(\theta))$ on both sides yields $0$. So $\theta=p(\theta)r(\theta)$. But then if we consider how the definition of ideal addition gives $(2,\theta)=(2)+(\theta)$ then we see

> $$(2,\theta)=(2)+(\theta)=(\theta+1)(p(\theta))+(p(\theta))(r(\theta))=(p(\theta))\big((\theta+1)+(r(\theta)).$$

Since we already know $(\theta+1)$ to be prime, it must be that $(\theta+1)\not\big|(r(\theta))$ or else $(\theta+1)|(2,\theta)$ a contradiction since $q(x)$ is not a cube modulo $2$. We conclude $(\theta+1)+(r(\theta))=\mathcal{O}_K$ so that $(2,\theta)=(p(\theta))$.

We turn our attentions to $(3,\theta)$. By using $\theta^3=3(3\theta+1)$ we wish to compute the norm of $\theta^3$. By looking at the $\Bbb Q$-basis for $K$ $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ we can compute the norm of $\alpha=3\theta+2$ by looking at the determinant of the matrix of the linear transformation induced by multiplication by $\alpha$ relative to this basis which is

> $$M_\alpha=
> \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 27 & 18 \\
> 3 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 3 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$$

which has determinant $8$. This is most easily done (by-hand) by row reducing once--the operation is just $R_1\to R_1-9R_3$--then expanding along the top row which now has only one non-zero entry.

We conclude $N(\theta)=3^3\cdot 2^3$. Since $(3\theta+2)$ factors as primes above $8$ and must be a perfect cube, we determine that $(3\theta+2) =(2(\theta+1)+\theta)$ must be equal to $(p(\theta))^3$, since we've already shown that $(2)$ factors as principal ideals and since clearly $3\theta+2\equiv \theta\equiv 1\mod{(\theta+1)}$. From this and our earlier deduction that $\theta=p(\theta)r(\theta)$, we have that $(r(\theta))^3=(3,\theta)^3$, and again since the RHS is the cube of a prime ideal, we have that $(r(\theta))=(3,\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $p(x)=x^3-9x-6$. We see that $p(-1)=-1+9-6=2$. Consequently the constant term of $p(x-1)$ is equal to two. But $p(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta+1$. Expanding $p(x-1)$ we get that $\theta+1$ is a factor of two in the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\theta]$. This gives you the answer for the ideal $(2,\theta+1)$.

The other two are trickier.

Answer (score 2):

A way to restrict your search is to note that if $(\alpha)$ is a principal ideal, $N$ is the ideal on norms, and $\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ is the norm on elements, then
$$
N((\alpha)) = \text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha).
$$